# Generating signals with Pi

Tags: pi-3, python-3, signal, matlab

I have a vector of 500 numbers and would like to output these at a sample rate of 1kHz, thus a signal time of 0.5seconds.
Is there any way to do this using a Pi?
Do the GPIO pins only allow for an On/Off Response? or using PWM to get a value somewhere in-between e.g. 3.3Vpin @75% PWM gives 2.475V. is there any way to get a pin to do PWM@75% for 0.001 seconds, then 50%for 0.001 seconds etc. etc.
Another way I thought I may be able to solve this is outputting the signal via the 3.5mm jack, is there a way to isolate the L+R+video channel in the jack to send an analogue version of this signal through? 
I would be gathering this signal at the output at a sample rate of 1kHz.
I am new to Pi and a previous MATLAB user trying to learn Python (slowly). Any whiff of a helping hand would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is practical using PWM.

The only method I know of to do the timing would be to use (my) [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) [waveform](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#wave_add_generic) feature which allows you to switch GPIO on and off for accurately timed periods at accurate times.  The maximum switching rate would be 500 kHz.  I doubt that would be enough to achieve the effect you are after in a millisecond frame.